# Can YOLO pictures have a bounded box that covering the whole picture?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, yolo, bounding-box, darknet

I wonder why YOLO pictures need to have a bounding box.
Assume that we are using `Darknet`. Each image need to have a corresponding `.txt` file with the same name as the image file. Inside the `.txt` file it need to be. It's the same for all YOLO frameworks that are using `bounded boxes` for labeling.

```
<object-class> <x> <y> <width> <height>
```

Where `x`, `y`, `width`, and `height` are relative to the image's width and height.

For exampel. If we goto this [page](https://public.roboflow.com/object-detection/thermal-dogs-and-people/1/download/darknet) and press `YOLO Darknet TXT` button and download the `.zip` file and then go to `train` folder. Then we can see a these files

```
IMG_0074_jpg.rf.64efe06bcd723dc66b0d071bfb47948a.jpg
IMG_0074_jpg.rf.64efe06bcd723dc66b0d071bfb47948a.txt
```

Where the `.txt` file looks like this

```
0 0.7055288461538461 0.6538461538461539 0.11658653846153846 0.4110576923076923 
1 0.5913461538461539 0.3545673076923077 0.17307692307692307 0.6538461538461539
```

Every image has the size `416x416`. This image looks like this:

[image]

My idéa is that every image should have `one` class. Only `one` class. And the image should taked with a camera like this.

[image]

This camera snap should been taked as:

1. Take camera snap
2. Cut the camera snap into desired size
3. Upscale it to square `416x416`

Like this:

[image]

And then every `.txt` file that correspons for every image should look like this:

```
<object-class> 0 0 1 1
```

**Question**

Is this possible for e.g `Darknet` or other framework that are using `bounded boxes` to labeling the classes?

Instead of let the `software` e.g `Darknet` upscale the bounded boxes to `416x416` for every class object, then I should do it and change the `.txt` file to `x = 0, y = 0, width = 1, height = 1` for every image that only having `one` class object.

Is that possible for me to create a `traing set` in that way and train with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Little disclaimer I have to say that I am not an expert on this, I am part of a project and we are using darknet so I had some time experimenting.

So if I understand it right you want to train with cropped single class images with full image sized bounding boxes.

It is possible to do it and I am using something like that but it is most likely not what you want.

Let me tell you about the problems and unexpected behaviour this method creates.

When you train with images that has full image size bounding boxes yolo can not make proper detection because while training it also learns the backgrounds and empty spaces of your dataset. More specifically objects on your training dataset has to be in the same context as your real life usage. If you train it with dog images on the jungle it won't do a good job of predicting dogs in house.

If you are only going to use it with classification you can still train it like this it still classifies fine but images that you are going to predict also should be like your training dataset, so by looking at your example if you train images like this cropped dog picture your model won't be able to classify the dog on the first image.

For a better example, in my case detection wasn't required. I am working with food images and I only predict the meal on the plate, so I trained with full image sized bboxes since every food has one class. It perfectly classifies the food but the bboxes are always predicted as full image.

So my understanding for the theory part of this, if you feed the network with only full image bboxes it learns that making the box as big as possible is results in less error rate so it optimizes that way, this is kind of wasting half of the algorithm but it works for me.

Also your images don't need to be 416x416 it resizes to that whatever size you give it, you can also change it from cfg file.

I have a code that makes full sized bboxes for all images in a directory if you want to try it fast.(It overrides existing annotations so be careful)

Finally boxes should be like this for them to be centered full size, x and y are center of the bbox it should be center/half of the image.

```
<object-class> 0.5 0.5 1 1
```

````
from imagepreprocessing.darknet_functions import create_training_data_yolo, auto_annotation_by_random_points
import os

main_dir = "datasets/my_dataset"

# auto annotating all images by their center points (x,y,w,h)
folders = sorted(os.listdir(main_dir))
for index, folder in enumerate(folders):
    auto_annotation_by_random_points(os.path.join(main_dir, folder), index, annotation_points=((0.5,0.5), (0.5,0.5), (1.0,1.0), (1.0,1.0)))

# creating required files
create_training_data_yolo(main_dir)
```
````

Comment: I have chaned my idea now. I will not scale the picture. Just have it normal with a bounded box. By the way. Darknet Tiny need pictures in size 416x416 for training. I'm building a software that automaticly can collect training data.

Comment: oh I didn't know tiny yolo needs resizing.

Comment: Yes. Yolo needs square size.

Comment: By the way! Can you try this? https://github.com/DanielMartensson/Darknet-Data-Creator/ 1. Download the project. Start the project with the command `mvn javafx:run`. You need to stand inside the folder. `mvn` is Maven command. `sudo apt-get install maven` if you are using `.deb` based inux systems.

Comment: Well I tried but I don't have a usb camera so all I can say is ui works ‍♂️, are you going to run the training as terminal process.

Comment: Yes. I'm going to run the training as terminal process by calling Darknet from Java. I will try to implement that today. I also made a GitHub repository that you might also like. https://github.com/DanielMartensson/Camera-Reporter

Comment: Hi again. Now I'm done with the project. https://github.com/DanielMartensson/Darknet-Data-Creator

Comment: I will look at it.

Comment: Thank you. Give me a reply if it's working for you.

Comment: The machine that I use for training has no ui. I tried it on a virtual ubuntu with my data file but it is saying "Couldn't open file: Desktop/obj.data". Isn't it using full path for command, also for mean average precision shouldn't it be map instead of mep.

Comment: You need to have `obj.data` inside a `folder` that are inside `darknet` folder.

Comment: Fixed the `-map` now.

Comment: I tried to call `darknet` where the arguments are absolut full path, That did not work, even if I do it with the terminal.

Comment: I also tried putting data file inside darknet but still same error. Absolute paths works for me on terminal. ‍♂️

Comment: Hmm..You are using Windows? Can post the stack trace in a issue? :)

Comment: Okay I misunderstood your previous comment, I was putting my data file either directly inside darknet folder or 2 nested folders that are inside darknet folder. It is working with single folder.

Comment: Good to hear! Have you tried to create your own data by using an USB camera? :)

Comment: I don't have a usb camera right now, I will write if I can test it.